Solving the Moutard PDE
I'm researching on discrete/semi-discrete/smooth differential geometry. Recently, I transformed one of my surface theory problems (in the smooth scenario) into the following Moutard PDE
$$h_{uv} = q\,h$$
where $h(u,v)$ and $q(u,v): [0,a]\times [0,b] \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are smooth functions on $(0,a)\times (0,b)$. I have the functions $h(u,0)$ and $h(0,v)$ and $q(u,v)$ as well.
By observing its discrete/semi-discrete counterparts I believe that it should have a unique solution by the boundaries that I provided. However, since my knowledge of PDE is very limited I don't know how to solve it in the smooth case.
I would very much appreciate if you can direct me on how to solve it. I would specially like to know if $h(u,0)$ and $h(0,v)$ being smooth is enough for getting the unique solution. Or should they be specifically analytic?
Extra Info:
In the special case that I am considering $q(u,v) = \cos(\omega(u,v))$ where $\omega(u,v)$ is a solution of the famous sine-Gordon equation:
$$\omega_{uv} = \sin{\omega}$$

Is that really all you know about $q$? If you have more information about $q$ it might make it easier.

@ResearchMath I added some extra info.

You should look up the literature on the sine-Gordon equation. The techniques for solving it should apply just as well to your equation. Your question is not about the standard initial value problem for the equation but for characteristic initial data ($u=c$ and $v=c$ are characteristic curves of the equation). So you should look for that.

@DeaneYang I did not understand what you mean by $u =c$ and $v =c$. what is $c$ here?

Classically this type of boundary value problem is called a "Goursat problem" (the boundaries where the data is provided are so-called characteristic curves (codim-1 surfaces really), as pointed out by Deane). Some quick searching for "2d Goursat problem" turns up this chapter from a book by Rubinstein & Rubinstein (1994).

@IgorKhavkine I think you pointed me to a very helpful reference. Thanks for the 2nd time helping me with my PDEs.

@IgorKhavkine Isn't it like this that for this problem the characteristics lines are the ones that are parallel to $u$ and $v$ axes? Therefore my initialization which is on $(u,0)$ and $(0,v)$ should not work right? or am I misled somewhere?

By $u=c$, I mean any line parallel to $u=0$. $c$ is just an arbitrary constant. As @IgorKhavkine points out these lines are characteristic "surfaces", so standard initial value problems do not apply.

A discussion of how to solve using inverse scattering techniques the Goursat problem for the sine-Gordon equation can be found here: https://epubs-siam-org.proxy.library.nyu.edu/doi/abs/10.1137/0134004

@DeaneYang thank you for the clarification but the link you provided is not working. It is jumping to a log in page.

Yes. You cannot get it through your university?

@DeaneYang the link just redirects into a login page of a NYU account. If you name the paper I can obtain it using my uni account.
